# Does learning front end development ( HTML, CSS, JS) useful for automated Testing carrier?

Tags: automated-tests

Is there a way that learning front end development helps with a deeper test automation? Or is mastering locators and Java automated scripts in Selenium enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need first step knowledge about **HTML/JS/css**, because you have to be able to localize element in the DOM, theirs states...

by this way you can write a program to click on that the button, or check if a modal is well displayed...

Also with tool like [ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/) you need some skill in **C#** to implement some behaviors for your auto-test